# How can I solve this limits: $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 } {{(\tan x - \sin x)\arctan x} \over {{1 \over 2}{x^4}}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know when $x \to 0$ , we have $sinx \sim arctanx \sim x $, but I have no idea when it comes to this form: $tanx -sinx$ , I'll appreciate it as long as a little hint.

Comment: there is an error in the title no? you want the limit when x-> 0 right?

Comment: @mvggz yeah..I have modified it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(x\to0)$

$$\eqalign{
& \tan x\sim\sin x\sim\arctan x\sim\arcsin x\sim x  \cr 
& 1 - \cos x\sim{1 \over 2}{x^2}  \cr 
& \tan x - \sin x = \tan x(1 - \cos x)\sim{1 \over 2}{x^3} \cr} $$

So the answer to the question is:
$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{(\tan x - \sin x)\arctan x} \over {{1 \over 2}{x^4}}}  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{{1 \over 2}{x^3} \cdot x} \over {{1 \over 2}{x^4}}}  \cr 
  &  = 1 \cr} $$